# Can a user import data from any microservice architecture with multiple schemas while importing data set from a database to HCL OneTest Data?

Tags: import, dataset, schema, multiple-schema

When a user imports the schema or sample data  set from database then what happens when the user wants to import the data from any microservice architecture with multiple schemas?

Answer (score 0):

In case, you want to import the data from any microservice architecture with multiple schemas then HCL OneTest Data lists all the schemas of the database. You can select the schemas that you want to import, and then choose the table or view of that schema.